# iOS. Create weblink to Google map from location

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I picked location on my Google map. I want to create a link from it

How can I do it? I did not find any posts about it

I have latitude and longitude

I need a link like this: https://www.google.com/maps/place/XL+Center/@41.768399,-72.6794744,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x89e6549e9033c1df:0x2222bb5c74fa750c!8m2!3d41.768399!4d-72.679174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you just want a link of Location, then this [thread](https://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/) can help you with that.

Here is a different way or option to get the link of Google Maps with address or location.

- **Place/Address**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/place/760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204`

- **Directions (with or without starting point)**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204/314+Avery+Avenue+Syracuse+NY+13204` >
> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir//760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204`

- **Directions (detect user’s current location as starting point)**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204`

- **Directions (with latitude / longitude coordinates)**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/43.12345,-76.12345` - *Directions (multiple destinations from set location)*
>
> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/760+W+Genesee+St+Syracuse+NY+13204/314+Avery+Ave+Syracuse+NY+13204/9090+Destiny+USA+Dr+Syracuse+NY+13204`

- **Query Search**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/search/food/43.12345,-76.12345,14z`

- **Destination Query**

> `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/Pinckney+Hugo+Group`

- **Linking to Google Street View**

> `http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=43.053522,-76.165687`

**For more information, check also these [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/create-a-google-maps-link-to-a-specific-location) and [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/89yzqIuosUI).**